# Multi insert inside a QueryFile

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I'm able to generate query for multi inserts or update thanks to pg-promise helpers but I was wondering if I could follow the advice of the author and put all queries outside of my javascript code (See here https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/SQL-Files and here : https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo).

When I use the insert helpers, the return query looks like :

```
INSERT INTO "education"("candidate_id","title","content","degree","school_name","start_date","still_in","end_date","picture_url") VALUES('6','My degree','Business bachelor','Bachelor +','USC','2018-05-15T02:00:00.000+02:00'::date,false,null::date,null),('6','Another degree','Engineering','Master degree','City University','2018-05-15T02:00:00.000+02:00'::date,false,null::date,null)
```

The idea is that I don't know how many inserts I want to do at the same time, so it has to be dynamic.

The following code doesn't work as I'm passing an array of object instead of an object :

```
db.none(`INSERT INTO "education"("candidate_id","title","content","degree","school_name","start_date","still_in","end_date","picture_url") 
      VALUES($<candidate_id>, $<title>, $<content>, $<degree>, $<school_name>, $<start_date>, $<still_in>, $<end_date>, $<picture_url>)`, data)
```

This code spreads the object but is still not correct to make a proper query :

```
db.none(`INSERT INTO "education"("candidate_id","title","content","degree","school_name","start_date","still_in","end_date","picture_url") 
      VALUES($1:list)`,
          [data])
```

Any idea ? Is it at least possible or in the case where I don't know how many records I want to insert in advance I have to call `pgp.helpers` everytime ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse static and dynamic SQL. SQL files are there for SQL queries that are mainly static, i.e. you still can inject dynamically a lot, but when most of the query is dynamic, there is no longer any point putting it into an SQL file.

And the `helpers` namespace is there for dynamic queries only. So you are asking about two separate things, to join things that do not need to be joined.

Comment: Okay I understand, in that case I'll continue to use the helpers inside my javascript code then. Thanks @vitaly-t and great job for this package !